# representation of shapes with respect to "empty" and "full" parts

Tags: geometry

Lets say I have 2 shapes that looks the same but they differ by the empty and full parts.

The shapes representation is by group of points along the contour and I can not assume they have some order.
We can assume that for each point we know in which direction is the "empty part" and in which direction is the "full part".
What can I add to the representation of the shapes that can indicate me that the shapes are not the same?
I tried to think about using normal vectors but I am stuck...

for example
 (the orange color indicates the "full" part and the white is the "empty" part):

[image]

another example:
[image]
I need to determine that the 2 shapes are not the same.

Thanks !

Comment: You can drink coffee out of the first one, but not the second one.

Comment: To put that another way, suppose that you're standing in the second region with a length of rope. The rope may be arranged in any way within the region, but you're holding the ends in both hands. No matter how it's arranged, you should be able to gather the rope so that it contracts to a point. Can you do the same in the first region?

Answer (score 1):

You could differentiate between the two based on whether points at infinity are included in the region or not.

In the OP's case, one way to implement the point-at-infinity test would be to pick a point with a minimum or maximum coordinate, move it a bit further away from origin (say, 10% further away from origin, along the minimum/maximum coordinate), and test whether that is included in the region. It is definitely "outside" the contour curve, and thus is always inside the region if points at infinity are inside, and outside if points at infinity are outside.

(In 2D computer graphics, the common way to avoid similar issues is to impose order on the contour curve, and then arbitrarily choosing the side on which the region  is, relative to the contour curve. Typically, left side is chosen to include the region, so that the boundary is defined counterclockwise if the region is inside the boundary, and clockwise if the region is outside the boundary. This also works for multiple non-intersecting contours, including nested contours.)

---

One way to compare the similarity between the two shapes, with an accepted boundary difference of $2\epsilon$, would be to expand and contract the boundary by $\epsilon$ with respect to the region, moving the test points along with the boundary, and test each test point for inclusion in both shapes. If each point yields the same result for both shapes-- *inside* or *outside* the region --, the shapes are similar. If even one point differs, the shapes are not similar. (That is, dissimilar shapes are rapidly detected, and comparing similar shapes requiring the most work.)

Expanding and contracting the boundary curve is not trivial, though. (Moving the test points along a boundary defined as a polygon is easier, especially if all polygon edges are longer than $2\epsilon$, and all vertices are at least $2\epsilon$ away from each other and from edges it does not participate in.)

Comment: Thanks! do you think that this way is good also to open contour shapes (please look on the second image I added)?

Comment: @user9: Yes, I think it would work well. (If the open contours are limited to e.g. a bounding box, instead of a point at infinity you can use one or more corner(s) of the bounding box (pick one that is further than $\epsilon$ away from the contour), for example.) I warmly recommend you do some simple numerical tests, using e.g. awk and gnuplot (if you know those well), or perhaps Python and Qt (for visual comparison -- you can create one window for each shape, and report the results to standard output (command line). I often find new approaches via exploratory testing this way.